# Creating new array of dates/data with missing dates/data added in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, time-series

I have four columns of river flow data in the format (year,month,day,data). I want to check through the data to ensure that there are not any missing chunks and if there are, to create a new data array ('newdates') with the missing dates (column 1) added in, along with NaN values for the missing data (column 2).

I am checking for the missing data by subtracting the datenum of the previous day, from the datenum of the current day (if it is greater than 1, then there is data missing). My code below works, but I am omitting the last day of the data each time. 
The loop I have generated to check each row is the length of the data minus 1, because if I allow it to be the length of the data, it won't be able to check the difference between the two last dates, as the date vector will not be large enough.I know this isn't an overly complex thing to do, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

%load a sample file of data in the format Year,Month,Date,Riverflow

```
>data=load('dmf_21002_279631_Q_COMPLETE_matlab.csv');  
>yr=data(:,1);  
>mth=data(:,2);  
>day=data(:,3);  
>flow=data(:,4);  
>dates=datenum([yr,mth,day]);  
>icounter=1;
```

%This is the counter for indexing the 'newdates'

```
>ndcounter=0
>for i =1:(length(dates)-1);  
    >ndcounter=ndcounter+1;  
    >if dates(i+1)-dates(i)==1;  
        >newdates(ndcounter,1)=dates(i,1);  
        >newdates(ndcounter,2)=data(i,4);  
    >elseif (dates(i+1)-dates(i))~=1;  
        >newdates(ndcounter,1)=dates(i,1);  
       > newdates(ndcounter,2)=data(i,4);
```

%count the number of days of data that are missing from the array

```
>daysmissing(icounter,1)=(dates(i+1)-dates(i))-1;
```

%create the missing datenums by adding ii on to the previous
%datenum (do this for the length of data missing)

```
>for ii=1:daysmissing;
            >newdates((i+ii),1)=((newdates(i))+ii);
           > newdates((i+ii),2)=NaN;
       > end

        >ndcounter=ndcounter+daysmissing;
        >disp('Missing data found');
       > missingidx(icounter)=i;
         >icounter=icounter+1;
    >end

>end
>newdates(newdates==-999)=NaN;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to look into the [`timeseries`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html) class. On `timeseries` objects, you can call `resample()` to create missing values.

MWE:

```
dates = datenum([2016 2016 2016], [4 4 4], [10 11 13]);
data = [0 1 3];
ts = timeseries(data, dates);
ts2 = ts.resample(datenum([2016 2016 2016 2016], [4 4 4 4], [10:13]));

figure(1); hold on;
ts.plot('bo--');
ts2.plot('rx:');
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I haven't used 'timeseries' before and it looks pretty useful. I'm in a bit of a bind 'time-wise' though at the moment, so what I really want is just to ensure that the current script works (and spend my own time looking at 'timeseries' afterwards). Do you have any suggestions as to how I would include the last day using my current script? Thanks.